# If statement returns false even if its true

Tags: jquery

I made timer so when `dro` is more than 1 I want button to have class `active` else to removeclass `if` statement works but `else` not. any solutions ?

```
    var dro = 5;
    var saboloo = 0;
    function setup(){
        var es = $('#dro');
        dro--;
        es.html(dro);
        if(dro == -1){
            es.html(clearInterval(setupInterval));
            $('.wait').html('Game started');
        }
    }
    var setupInterval = setInterval(setup,1000);

    function manamde(){
        if(dro > 1){
            $('button').addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('button').removeClass('active');
        }
    }
    manamde();
```

````html
  <h1 class="wait"><span value="5" id="dro">5</span>Seconds before the game starts</h1>
<button>start</button>```
````

Comment: What `else`? There is no `else` in your code. And what `button`? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Fixed,Sorry, my bad.

Comment: What is your CSS for the "active" class? Where do you call the `manamde` function? Still so many gaps. Present a [mcve].

Comment: Pretty sure `dro` is greather than `1`, then.

Comment: `manamde` is never called, and why would use pass the result of `clearInterval` (which is `undefined`) to the `html` method??

Comment: What's the purpose of the "value" property on a `span`? That's not valid HTML.

Comment: After the latest question update you only call `manamde` before any timer tick has happened. After that you never call it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've just forgotten to call the `manamde()` function from within `setup()`.

The code you provided will just call it once on initialisation (and therefore add the class `.active` as `dro` is initially set as 5), but not check again with each firing of the `setInterval`. The `if` statement itself is working absolutely fine.

I've tweaked your code below and added some styling to `.active` to demonstrate that it is working.

Let me know if this wasn't what you were hoping for.

---

## Demo

```js
var dro = 5;
var saboloo = 0;

function setup() {

  var es = $('#dro');
  
  dro--;
  
  es.html(dro);
  
  if (dro == -1) {
  
    es.html(clearInterval(setupInterval));
    $('.wait').html('Game started');
    
  }
  
  // Add a call to run manamde() from within setup
  // This will then run each second
  manamde();
  
}

var setupInterval = setInterval(setup, 1000);

function manamde() {
  if (dro > 1) {
    $('button').addClass('active');
  } else {
    $('button').removeClass('active');
  }
}

// This is still needed to add .active before the first setInterval is completed
manamde();
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="wait"><span id="dro">5</span> seconds before the game starts</h1>
<button>start</button>
```